# Sorting an array of pointers to an object alphabetically by their member variables

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, compare, operator-overloading

I have an array of Person objects that contain a member variable, name. I am trying to order them alphabetically using an overloaded comparison operator that uses string::compare to compare the strings in the objects.

```
bool Person::operator==(Person p) {
    if (name.compare(p.name) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this works and gives me the correct result but I don't know how I can use this to order the names in the array alphabetically.

I have looked around and seen that documentation on string::compare says

> ## relation between compared string and comparing string
>
> - 0  They compare equal
> - <0 Either the value of the first character that does not match is lower in > the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string > is shorter.
> - ,>0  Either the value of the first character that does not match is greater >in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is longer.

I can't figure out a way to solve my problem with this information though.

Am I on the right track for what I'm trying to do or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see the *pointers* mentioned in your title in *any* this. nor do I see any calls to a sort routine (such as `std::sort`) that is using your custom comparator (which should be `operator <` if you're going to use `std::sort`). In short, I see no [minimal, *complete*, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The standard library has you covered with [template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Answer (score 2):

Your operator is correctly defined, but it is not the operator you are looking for. You want to define the operator <, then use std::sort.

Comment: So I would use bool  Person::operator<(Person p) { if (name.compare(p.name) < 0) { return true; } }?

Comment: @luke_k `bool Person::operator <(const Person& p) const { return name < p.name; }`